# UseEffect and useCallback still causes infinite loop in react project

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect, usecallback

I can't seem to resolve an infinite loop issue in my react project.

I'm working on a daily-log react app. Let me explain the project briefly. Here is the picture of the code for quick view:

[image: Here is the picture of the code for quick view]

The same code is available at the bottom.

**The structure** (from top to bottom)

1. The `DailyLog` component has a form that uses `Question` components into which props are passed.
2. The `Question` component uses the props to display a question and description. It also contains an `Input` component into which props are further passed down.
3. The `Input` component takes the props and renders the appropriate form input field.

**The logic** (from bottom to top)

1. The `Input` component handles it's own `inputState`.  The state is changed when the user inputs something and the `onChangeHandler` is triggered.
2. The `Input` component also has a `useEffect()` hook that calls an `onInput()` function that was passed down as props from `DailyLog`.
3. The `onInputHandler()` in the `DailyLog` component updates the `formState` which is the form-wide state containing all input field values. The `formState` is amended depending on which input field is filled at the time.
4. The `onInputHandler()` uses the `useCallback()` hook which is supposed to stop an infinite loop caused by any parent/child re-renders. But it doesn't work :frowning:

What's wrong in the code? What am I missing here? Code provided below:

```
//DailyLog.js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

import Question from '../components/FormElements/Question';
import questionData from '../components/DailyLog/questionData';
import './DailyLog.css';

const DailyLog = () => {
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState();

    const onInputHandler = useCallback(
        (inputId, inputValue) => {
            setFormState({
                ...formState,
                [inputId]: inputValue,
            });
        },
        [formState]
    );

    return (
        <main className="container">
            <form action="" className="form">
                <Question
                    id="title"
                    element="input"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Day, date, calendar scheme"
                    onInput={onInputHandler}
                />

                <Question
                    id="focus"
                    question={questionData.focusQuestion}
                    description={questionData.focusDescription}
                    element="textarea"
                    placeholder="This month's focus is... This week's focus is..."
                    onInput={onInputHandler}
                />
            </form>
        </main>
    );
};

export default DailyLog;
```

```
//Question.js
import React from 'react';

import Input from './Input';
import './Question.css';

const Question = props => {
    return (
        <div className="form__group">
            {props.question && (
                <label className="form__label">
                    <h2>{props.question}</h2>
                </label>
            )}

            <small className="form__description">{props.description}</small>

            <Input
                id={props.id}
                element={props.element}
                type={props.type}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                onInput={props.onInput}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Question;
```

```
//Input.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import './Input.css';

const Input = props => {
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState();

    const { id, onInput } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        onInput(id, inputState);
    }, [id, onInput, inputState]);

    const onChangeHandler = event => {
        setInputState(event.target.value);
    };

    // check if question element type is for input or textarea
    const element =
        props.element === 'input' ? (
            <input
                id={props.id}
                className="form__field"
                type={props.type}
                value={inputState}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                onChange={onChangeHandler}
            />
        ) : (
            <textarea
                id={props.id}
                className="form__field"
                rows="1"
                value={inputState}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                onChange={onChangeHandler}
            />
        );

    return <>{element}</>;
};

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove id and onInput from useEffect sensivity list

```
useEffect(() => {
        onInput(id, inputState);
}, [inputState]);
```

And set default value of inputState to '' as follow:

```
const [inputState, setInputState] = useState('');
```

---

To prevent 'A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled error in ReactJS'. Also you can init formState:

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({title:'', focus:''});
```

Comment: Also now in useCallback(), if I console.log(formState), there is a 1 step delay. If I type anything in the input field, for example 1 then 2 then 3. The console first logs undefined, then 1 then 2.

Comment: setFormState is async so when you log formState you actually log previous formState, log inputValue and you see it's not 1 step delayed!